# Google/Firebase reCaptcha not working with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, recaptcha

Following documentation for new Firebase phone authentication. They have introduced a recaptcha as a security/spam measure. According to the js documentation the recaptcha is injected into the DOM with:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
```

However this does not appear to work in AngularJS. I have tried swapping out window. for $window and ensured this was available in my controller, but still no luck.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the js documentation I've been following:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting problem, but I don't think it's because of angular. Does the 'recaptcha-container' exist as an ID in your html? Does that line of code execute?

Comment: yes, i'm simply using a div with the id="recaptcha-container". Also interestingly, if I assign  the firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier to a $scope variable and console.log it, I can see it does have some form of object populated.

Comment: Gotcha, ok two more things, what if you tried doing ```$scope.$apply()```? I doubt it will fix it, but just an idea. And do you see an errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with the scope.apply, nothing in the console. Just scouring some of the Firebase/Ionic forums now so will update when I find the solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I discussed this in a thread on the GitHub repo: [Support for PhoneNumber Auth #990](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/990)

Heres a copy-paste, it will get you signed in via phone and obviously get the recaptcha working:

UPDATED: (Resolved)

I can confirm I am now able to sign in via mobile from angular!
Make sure if you want to use the ReCaptcha as a widget, ensure that that the containing div is created when the object is initialized.

I prefer the 'invisible' method, so I first put an empty div somewhere on my html page:

`<div id="phone-sign-in-recaptcha"></div>`

and inside ngOnInit() i have instantiated it:

```
window['phoneRecaptchaVerifier'] = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('phone-sign-in-recaptcha', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': function(response) {
    // reCAPTCHA solved - will proceed with submit function
  },
  'expired-callback': function() {
    // Reset reCAPTCHA?
  }
});
```

The form submit function which is fired when the recaptcha is solved is:

```
this.auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber,     window['phoneRecaptchaVerifier']).then(function(confirmationResult){
  var code = prompt('We have send a code to ' + phoneNumber + ', please enter it here', "");
  if (code) {
    confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
      // User signed in successfully.
      // Reset reCAPTCHA?
      // ...
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
      // Reset reCAPTCHA?
      // ...
    });
  }
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

In order to access the global variable `grecaptcha` to call `grecaptcha.reset([widgetId])`, which you will want to do in the case that the recaptcha has expired or there is an error signing in and users need to try again.

`npm install @types/grecaptcha --save`

and back in your component module where your recaptcha is, directly under your imports declare the variable:
`declare var grecaptcha: any;`

in my code I have replaced the comment `// Reset reCAPTCHA?` with the following call:

```
    window['phoneRecaptchaVerifier'].render().then(function(widgetId) {
      grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
    });
```

All works great now!

Comment: P.S. note the use of: window['phoneRecaptchaVerifier'] and NOT window.phoneRecaptchaVerifier